# react using .map() inside component prop attribute

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to conditionally render a component based on if that user is online. The problem im experiencing is with the `status` prop on my `MessengerFriend` component. In my conditional statement it is returning both `'online'` and `'offline'`, but when I only use the equivalent `if` It returns the online status correctly. My initial thought was that using `onlineFriends.map()` is returning both statuses because there are in fact users both online and offline.

```
const [friendsList, setFriendsList] = useState([])
const [onlineFriends, setOnlineFriends] = useState([])


let mappedFriendChatList = friendsList.map(friend => {
    return(
      <MessengerFriend 
        key={friend.friend_id}
        value={friend}
        status={onlineFriends.map(onlineFriend => onlineFriend.userId == friend.user_id ? 'online' : 'offline')}
      />
    )
  })
```

I'm expecting to have a list of all my friends and there status `'online'` and `'offline'` to display correctly

Comment: What does the MessengerFriend component do ?

Answer (score 0):

Map is the wrong method for this use-case; `some` is what you need.

```
{onlineFriends.some(onlineFriend => onlineFriend.userId === friend.user_id) ? 'online' : 'offline'}
```

You could also use `filter` with a length check on the result array, or `find` (which would work identically to `some` in this case).

Comment: The solution works with `.some` but the implementation isn't correct. Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction